# rails devise logger log level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise 2.0.4 in my rails 3.2 application. I am using the built in devise action mailer to send welcome and password reset emails. One thing I noticed is that devise does not log the email headers to the log file in production environment but does it in the development environment, in production it just logs a line "Sent mail to XXXXXX". I am trying to figure out two things:

- How do I give devise my own logger with a log level set?
- Is there a way to change the log level that is set in devise, it looks like it is set to INFO now, so can I set it to debug.

Thank you

Comment: the logging system in rails is very poor. i don't think that you can do it on such a fine grained level. you could change the default logging level of you application if that helps.